# How to list all the possible functions of given structure?

Tags: functions, function-construction, parametric-functions, group-theory, tuples

I can run this command :

```
Tuples[{ Tuples[{x, y, z}, 2],   {a, b, c}}]
```

to list all combinations that looks like:

```
{{{x, x}, a}, {{x, x}, b}, {{x, x}, c}, {{x, y}, a}, {{x, y}, ... }
```

Now I want to combine Tuples with something like Groupings (there might be other functions more suitable for this). I have a list of unary or binary functions. For example, Func1 and Func2 are binary, Func3 is unary. I want to list all the possible combinations that looks like:

```
Func2(Func1(x, x), Func3(a))
Func2(Func1(Func3(x), x), a)
Func2(Func3(Func1(x,x)), a)
```

Above 3 functions are examples for {{x, x}, a}. There could be other possibilities such as :

```
Func3(Func2(Func1(x, x), a)
```

I am not sure if Mathematica can do this. If not, maybe we can simplify the problem so that Mathematica could handle it. How to simplify the problem then?

The depth should be no more than 4, otherwise there will be too many solutions.

If it is very difficult to solve this problem ,  we can try other ways to constrain the complexity --- narrow down the search space. We could potentially add a constraint saying that each function FuncX can only be used once or twice.

Comment: To what depth should the expressions go? If each `funcN` returns an element that can be an argument of another function, then the nesting is potentially infinite.

Comment: Hi Shredderroy, That's a good question, "Func2(Func1(Func3(x), x), a)" should be the deepest .

Comment: What about `func2[func1[x, func3[x]], a]`? Is that also one of the expressions that should be generated?

Comment: Yes Shredderroy, binary functions are treated the same. They can be swapped to create new functions

Comment: Is `Func2(Func3(x), Func1(x, a))` invalid?

Comment: @Coolwater, it is invalid for this case. the all the functions i listed follow the same 'tree-structure' as {{x, x}, a} --- except that a unary function can be applied anywhere